# Fixing text size inconsistancies in my website for different browsers, specificly mobile browsers (Tried reset.css and multiple font formats)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, cross-browser

**Issue:**

Text is displaying in different sizes on different pages of my website, despite the same code being used. This is effecting specifically mobile browsers. For example, my text is sized appropriately in Firefox desktop, however, in Firefox mobile, the text is 200% what it should be, but only for a few specific pages, while other pages display just fine. The "Show Desktop Site" slider does not seem to effect the issue. Some mobile browsers display everything just fine, like Samsung's default browser.

**What I've tried:**

Some answers are suggesting reset.css (https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), but I can't really find anyone's explanation of how to implement this, so I just assume I'm supposed to declare reset.css as my css in my html, then declare my actual css to override it. If that's not how to implement this, please tell me specifically. Every discussion around this seems to just say "implementation is different for every site" without saying anything specific.

I have also tried declaring multiple font formats for max compatibility, however, it doesn't really help. I'm using WOFF, TFF, and SVG. This is what my @font-face css looks like:

```css
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'main_font';
    src: url('fonts/SpecialElite-Regular.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/SpecialElite-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/SpecialElite-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/SpecialElite-Regular.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

**Example:**

Here is Firefox Mobile on a page that is displaying properly:
[image]

Here is also Firefox Mobile on another page, that uses the same code, but displays larger text:
[image]

Here is the html snippet for the page that's working correctly:

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="c">~ Filters ~<br><a href="art.html?filter=All"> All </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=New"> New </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=1920x1080Wallpaper"> 1920 x 1080 Wallpaper </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=1080x1920Wallpaper"> 1080 x 1920 Wallpaper </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=Glitch"> Glitch </a><br><a href="art.html?filter=Cartoon"> Cartoon </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=Pixel"> Pixel </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=PencilArt"> Pencil Art </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=Paper"> Paper </a> ~ <a href="art.html?filter=3D"> 3D </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the page that is displaying larger text:

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="c">~ Filters ~<br><a href="textures.html?filter=All">All</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=New">New</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Organic">Organic</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Stone">Stone</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Dirt">Dirt</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Food">Food</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Water">Water</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Mold">Mold</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Plastic">Plastic</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Wood">Wood</a><br><a href="textures.html?filter=Alpha">Alpha</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Smears">Smears</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Plant">Plant</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Technology"> Technology </a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Paper">Paper</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Repeating">Repeating</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Books">Books</a> ~ <a href="textures.html?filter=Metal">Metal</a></div>
</div>
```

Both code snippets were taken from inspect element on a desktop rather than mobile, because I don't know how to inspect element on a mobile. This code is also generated via a javascript that runs on "window.onload" using Document Object Model methods. If I need to post the javascript, let me know, but it doesn't make any sense that it would output different html on mobile and desktop. If you want to dig around yourself with inspect element, the url is:

Working correctly on mobile: https://zanzindorf.com/art.html

Larger text on mobile: https://zanzindorf.com/textures.html

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also a note: I just found a "Mobile mode simulator" for Firefox which can be used by pressing Ctrl+Shift+M in desktop Firefox. This displays the text just fine in the simulation, which is very strange. So either the simulation is wrong, or my phone is weird. I'm certain it's not a cache issue. I've deleted the cache from the in-app settings as well as androids app list (Firefox>Storage>Clear Cache). Still no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: "Font Boosting"

It's aparently an automated feature to some browsers which resizes text under certain conditions.

Solution: add this line to the appropriate section in your CSS:

```css
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

The world makes more sense now :)